# Where to locate certificates and keys on Centos 6.5

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl-certificate

Looking at my Centos 6.5 /etc/pki/ directory, I see the following system generated directories:

```
[root@vps ~]# ls /etc/pki
CA  ca-trust  java  nssdb  rpm-gpg  rsyslog  tls
[root@vps ~]# ls /etc/pki/CA
certs  crl  newcerts  private
[root@vps ~]# ls /etc/pki/ca-trust
README  extracted  source
[root@vps ~]# ls /etc/pki/tls
cert.pem  certs  misc  openssl.cnf  private
[root@vps ~]#
```

When creating self signed keys, I created the following three files, and have located them as shown:

- /etc/pki/tls/private/mysite_key.pem (In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, I
  set `SSLCertificateKeyFile` to this value)
- /etc/pki/tls/private/mysite_csr.pem (In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, I
  don't use this value)
- /etc/pki/tls/certs/mysite_crt.pem (In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, I set `SSLCertificateFile` to this value)

Is this the "official" place to locate them when using Centos 6.5 and Apache 2.2?  Note that Apache was installed via `yum` and not compiled.  I realize it might not matter, but would like to get in the practice of locating them where most people do.

When using a CA certificate, should I locate them elsewhere?

Also, when using a CA certificate, should I not set `SSLCertificateFile`, but set `SSLCACertificateFile` to the CA certificate?  (EDIT.  When doing so, Apache errors out when not using `SSLCertificateFile`, but instead using `SSLCACertificateFile`)

I also have `SSLCertificateChainFile` which must be set to `sub.class1.server.ca.pem`.  Where should this file be located?

Thank you

Comment: Why the downvote?  There are multiple viable locations for Centos, and other distributions use totally different locations.  I know it doesn't mater since I could set up httpd.conf however I want, but there likely is a "right" place to locate them.

Comment: I think you want to look at the update-ca-trust man page. It is ... quite comprehensive, to say the least. For future RHEL versions (from RHEL 7 on, I guess), we will have http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SharedSystemCertificates which already is in fedora 19/20.